# Merge CATextLayer and UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, calayer, uigraphicscontext

I want to merge My CATextLayer with UIImage to one UIImage. I'm using this code:

```
let textViewLayer = CATextLayer()
        textViewLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: lockText.imagePositionX, y: lockText.imagePositionY), size: lockImageView.frame.size)
        textViewLayer.string = lockText.textText
        textViewLayer.font = lockText.textFont.fontName
        textViewLayer.fontSize = lockText.textFontSize
        textViewLayer.foregroundColor = lockText.color.CGColor

        let textView = UIView(frame: lockImageView.frame)
        textView.layer.addSublayer(textViewLayer)

        lockImageView.addSubview(textView)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(lockImageView.frame.size)
        textViewLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()


        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext is NIL. Could someone tell, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not you use `NString.drawInRect:withAttributes` instead? You don't need to create a text layer to compose a image with text watermark for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this code to solve my problem:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
            image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height))
            let rect = CGRectMake(lockText.imagePositionX, lockText.imagePositionY, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            lockText.color.set()

            let text = lockText.textText as NSString
            text.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: [NSFontAttributeName : lockText.textFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : lockText.color])
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```